# Ubuntu 20.04 setting PREEMPT_RT - Loading initial ramdisk

Tags: boot, kernel, realtime

I am trying to update the kernel of Ubuntu from `5.8.0-50-generic` to `5.9.1-rt20` (because there was no patches for `5.8.*`, not sure why), but the system freezes after `Loading initial ramdisk`. Same thing in recover mode.

The computer is Fujitsu celsius M770power. OS is Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. `dis_ucode_ldr` option is set, BIOS is updated (popular fixes on the Internet).

I know it is not very detailed, but I am ready to provide all needed logs. Thank you.

*P.S. Ubuntu was not my choice and I can't switch to other distro.*

Comment: Patches for what?  Only security fixes are back-ported to current or supported Ubuntu kernels, and rather than use a non-Ubuntu kernel (meaning all security patching falls on you), I'd have opted for the next 20.04 HWE kernel which is 5.11 (and is already packaged!); why did you choose 5.9 & a non-Ubuntu? kernel)

Comment: Real-time patches for kernel. I download the kernel's sourse, the [patch](https://kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/rt), fuse them together and compile. Like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51669724/install-rt-linux-patch-for-ubuntu).

Why RT? Because I have to operate with hardware, and I need it. Why ```5.9.1```? Because it's the closest version to ```5.8.0```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grub's "initrd" could not load ramdisk image. The problem was solved by installing and configurating of [systemd-boot](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Systemd-boot).